# Generalising the cross product to infinite dimensions, does $v \times v = 0$ hold also in infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, orthogonality, cross-product

Consider I have a vector space $V$ with inner product and a bilinear map $b : V \times V \to V$

i)  such that if $z = b(u,v)$ for two $u,v \in V$, then
$$
 z \perp u \quad \mbox{ and } \quad z \perp v.
$$
ii) if $u, v \in V$ are perpendicular, i.e. $u \perp v$, then
$$
 ||b(u,v)|| = ||u||||v||.
$$
These definitions are motivated by an axiomatic introduction of the cross product, see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cross+product).

Now I want to show that for every $v \in V$ we have $b(v,v) = 0$.

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then this follows by the fact that in an $n$-dimensional space, if $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ are orthogonal and non-zero, then $m \le n$ (because orthogonality of non-zero vectors implies linear independence). For if $v \in V, v \ne 0$ then the vectors
$$
 M = \{ v, b(v,v), b(v,b(v,v)), \ldots, b(v, b(v, \ldots, b(v,v))) \}
$$
are all orthgonal, to simplify notation suppose we have a $n = 4$ dimensional space. Then 
$$
 b(v, b(v, b(v, b(v, v))) = 0
$$
which implies by ii)
\begin{align*}
 0 & = ||b(v, b(v, b(v, b(v,v)))|| \\
   & = ||v|| ||b(v, b(v, b(v,v)))|| \\
   & = ||v|| ||v|| ||b(v, b(v,v))|| \\
   & = ||v|| ||v|| ||v|| ||b(v,v)||
\end{align*}
which implies $||b(v,v)|| = 0$, because $v \ne 0$, which implies that $b(v,v)$ is the zero vector.

But does this also hold if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, if not can you give an example were it fails?

Comment: Note the statement given on the link that you've provided: *In any other finite dimension* (dimensions other than $3$ and $7$), *there are no binary cross products at all*.  Why should there be a binary cross-product that works for infinitely many dimensions, then?

Comment: Because maybe in the proof finite-dimensionality is crucial... maybe you are right, but in this case I am just interested in a simple proof that $b(v,v) = 0$ (do you know one without using finite-dimensionality?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* such a bilinear form exists, it must satisfy $b(v,v) = 0$.

Let $w = b(v,v)$, and consider $b(v, v+w)$. By property i) and bilinearity, 
\begin{align*}
0 &= \langle v+w, b(v,v+w)\rangle\\
&= \langle v, b(v,v+w)\rangle + \langle w, b(v,v+w)\rangle\\
& = \langle w, b(v,v+w)\rangle\\
&= \langle w, b(v,v)\rangle + \langle w, b(v,w)\rangle\\
&= \langle w, b(v,v)\rangle\\
&= \|w\|^2
\end{align*}
and $w=0$.

Note that the above requires that $V$ be an inner product space; if you want to generalize the cross product to "all" of infinite-dimensional Euclidean space you will first need to write down a definition of $\perp$ for vectors that are not in $\ell^2$.